# trigger function if scroll reaches a certain point only once. Not every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if my users arrive at a certain point in my page. SO I created the following JS code:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#page2').position().top){

    alert("trigger");
    }
})
```

Which checks if the users reached my id="page2".  But I want this to trigger ONLY once, no matter if the users goes back up and back down, right now it gets trigger everytime the page2.position().top = scrollTop.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you just have this `scroll` event only on this page?

Comment: You could add a flag indicating it has been triggered already. Add a variable `triggeredAlert = false` and change it to true once triggered. Then add an if statement checking if it has been triggered already, and if not, trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`event.namespace`](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) and [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/off) to unbind event handler after execution of desired statement.

```
$(document).on('scroll.something', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#page2').position().top) {
        //Do something

        //Unbind the event
        $(document).off('scroll.something')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to achieve your desired output.

```
var checkonce = false;
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#page2').position().top){
       if(checkonce == false) {
         alert("trigger");
         checkonce = true;
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `off` the scroll event on your `document` after the first `scroll` has reached.

**Edit:** Also it would be better if you name your events, Which will help us remove the specific event by using the name. (`Satpal already mentioned this in his answer before me, I am improving my answer standard as well.`)

```
$(document).on('scroll.Page2ScrollEvent', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#page2').position().top){

     $(this).off('scroll.Page2ScrollEvent'); // remove specific scroll event.

     alert("trigger");
    }
})
```